# Bash script: Rename Volume

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal

i want to rename the current Volume dynamically to "Test", and i don't know how its named right now.

This would be my go-to option: But i don't know the old name.

```
sudo diskutil rename "Macintosh HD" "Test"
```

Edit: Operationsystem: MacOS Mojave 10.14.x

Comment: I actually came up with a complicated way and a easy solution. sudo diskutil rename / "Test" is working. However, sudo diskutil information /Volumes/* | grep 'Volume Name' | awk '{ print $3 }’
 would give me the current volume name to set it as a variable.. (regarding only 1 volume is attached)

Answer (score 0):

rename label

```
# find disk path
sudo blkid
# rename
sudo e2label /dev/sdxN Test
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo diskutil rename / "Test"
```

Since there is a symlink on /Volumes/yourVolume ..